# Swift 3 which is the best way to store of an Object with array etc

Tags: swift

I started to develop with Swift 3 and i´m getting crazy. Following Situation:

```
class subObject
{
  var name : String
  var list : [Int]

  init( _name : String, _list : [Int] ){
    self.name = _name
    self.list = _list
   }
 }

class mainObject
{
  var subObjectList : [subObject]

  init( _list : [subObject] ){
    self.subObjectList = _list
  }
}

var data : [mainObject]
```

Which way is state of the art to store `var data : [mainObject]` persistently. I've already unsuccessfully tried `.plist`and `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Sorry but my english is worse.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what problem that you are facing?? You want the `subObjectList` to be an subObject array?

Comment: Please try `var subObjectList : Array<subObject>`

Comment: What problems did you face with NSUserDefaults? It is a definite way of storing data, so it may be worth visiting again. Core data is another way of storing data - perhaps with a steeper learning curve.

Comment: @JackyShek There is no difference: `Array<subObject>` and  `[subObject]` are synonyms.

Comment: @vadian Yes, but i have faced the problem in swift 2

Comment: @ZombieIK You'll have to be more specific with the term "the problem", for us to help you more effectively.

Comment: @JackyShek There is no difference in Swift 2, too

Comment: @vadian to be more specific my problems is that the Xcode does not allow  me to do at `[Class]` this way when i add a class. After changing `Array<Class>`, it allows me again.

Comment: @JackyShek No. `Array<Class>` is the same as `[Class]`, this is just syntactic sugar, the declaration is the same. It's impossible to have one without having the other unless you're still using Swift 1.1.

Comment: @EricAya Opps, sorry my bad. That is really Swift 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSCoding` cannot be used because the classes aren't subclasses of `NSObject`.

Since all properties in both classes are property list compliant you could add a computed property `propertyListRepresentation` and an appropriate initializer.

Class names are supposed to start with a capital letter and parameters starting with an underscore are unusual in Swift.

```
class SubObject
{
    var name : String
    var list : [Int]

    init(name : String, list : [Int] ){
        self.name = name
        self.list = list
    }

    init?(dictionary : [String:Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let list = dictionary["list"] as? [Int] else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.list = list
    }

    var propertyListRepresentation : [String:Any] {
        return ["name" : name, "list" : list]
    }
}

class MainObject
{
    var subObjectList : [SubObject]

    init(list : [SubObject] ){
        self.subObjectList = list
    }

    init(propertyList : [[String:Any]] ){
        self.subObjectList = propertyList.flatMap{ SubObject(dictionary: $0) }
    }

    var propertyListRepresentation : [[String:Any]] {
        return subObjectList.map{ $0.propertyListRepresentation }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
let subs = [SubObject(name: "Foo", list: [1, 2, 3]), SubObject(name: "Bar", list: [4, 5, 6])]
let main = MainObject(list: subs)

let list = main.propertyListRepresentation
let data = try! PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: list, format: .xml, options: 0)

print(String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)!)

let restoredList =  try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[String:Any]]
let restoredMain = MainObject(propertyList: restoredList)
```